# Computing the integral $ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\phi^2+\phi}\cdot \phi^{2} \ln(1-2x\cos\phi+x^2)\, d\phi. $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, contour-integration

Integrate
$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\phi^2+\phi}\cdot \phi^{2} \ln(1-2x\cos\phi+x^2) \, d\phi.
$$
Something that may help $(1-2x\cos\phi+x^2)=(1-xe^{i\phi})(1-xe^{-i\phi})$.  And using the series expansion
$$
\ln(1-z)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}
$$
where $|z=xe^{\pm i\phi}| \leq 1$.  The series is absolutely and uniformly convergent.
Any method is okay.

Comment: What contest is this from?

Comment: Personally, this integral value can not be presented as elementary form. So numerical method would be introduced in this question.

Comment: @RonGordon bulgarian math team question at sofia university

Comment: This may or may not be useful, but for $|x| <1$, the integral can be expressed as $$-2e^{1/4} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \phi^{2} e^{-(\phi-1/2)^2} \cos(k \phi) \ d \phi $$

Are you sure the upper limit should be $2 \pi$ and not $\infty$?

Comment: @RandomVariable Wow, surprised I haven't realized this.  The upper bound IS supposed to be $\infty$. I had been thinking $2\pi$ because the same integral with $\cos(\phi)$ instead of $\phi^2\cdot\exp{...}$ I had done right before this one and for this case the bounds are 0 to $2\pi$.  THANKS again